# Is it possible to embed an OpenType font in a PDF with RDLC?

Tags: .net, pdf, fonts, embed, rdlc

I'm using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer to generate some PDF, I just haven't found any way to embed an OpenType font in the PDF, is that possible?

if I generate a .xls or .doc file (excel and word) the font is embedded normally, if I generate a PDF through the generated Word the font is also embedded, only when I generate a PDF directly does not embed the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by converting the file from otf to ttf, it worked for me.